# Powershell write to vbscript console(cscript.exe)

Tags: powershell, vbscript, powershell-2.0, windows-scripting

I have a requirement of running powershell script in silent mode through vbscript(cscript.exe).

Basic steps for script are as follow.

vbscript

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Welcome..."
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "First Step..."
WScript.Sleep Int(2000)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell"): objShell.Run "powershell -nologo -file D:\basic\child.ps1" ,0,true
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Script Completed."
WScript.Sleep Int(5000)
```

powershell script

```
Write-Host "Some Text Printed"
Start-Sleep -s 2
```

Atthis point, I like the powershell script to write to vbscript(cscript.exe) console.

I am running vb script as follow.

```
cscript d:\basic\script.vbs
```

Is there any work around for this requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need execute a command line in a Visual Basic Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501044/i-need-execute-a-command-line-in-a-visual-basic-script)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the answer to the question that I linked as a possible duplicate, you can do something like this:

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Welcome..."
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "First Step..."
WScript.Sleep Int(2000)
res = getCommandOutput("powershell -nologo -file D:\basic\child.ps1")
WScript.StdOut.Write res
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Script Completed."
WScript.Sleep Int(5000)

Function getCommandOutput(theCommand)

    Dim objShell, objCmdExec
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objCmdExec = objshell.exec(thecommand)
    getCommandOutput = objCmdExec.StdOut.ReadAll

end Function
```